# CloudFormation / Terraform for heroku?

Tags: heroku

Are there any official (or unofficial) ways of storing entire heroku configurations as code?

I think *most* heroku configurations can be stored in a bash script. But things like scheduled jobs and the like still have to be performed manually.

Is there *any* way to store entire app configurations as code so that the setup can be used directly or as a starting point for other applications?

Answer (score 0):

I since learned that you can indeed use terraform with heroku.

Source:

- [Using Terraform with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-terraform-with-heroku)